# AngularJs: Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined in debugger mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, referenceerror, angular-controller

I have the following code:

***Html***

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   {{message}}!
    <button ng-click="changeMessage()">change Message</button>
</div>
```

---

***AngularJs***

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.message = 'Hello $scope';
    $scope.newMessage = 'Hello World';
    $scope.changeMessage = function(){
        $scope.message = $scope.newMessage;//debugger;
    }
}
```

---

In this scenario, there is no problem. 
But, if you change this line:

`$scope.message = $scope.newMessage;`

with:

`debugger;`

then click the button, while the console is open, and write `$scope`, you'll get this error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined`

So my questions are:

- Why the `$scope` is accessible when you use the `$scope` inside the function, and is not accessible in debug mode (when you are not using the `$scope` somewhere in the function)
- How to work with `$http` under this circumstances, because `$http` is not accessible too

<kbd>**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19077/)**</kbd>

*Note: Maybe this is duplicate question, but I didn't find straight explanation for this issue, and solution as well*